# Enumeration yielded no results while calling stored procedure from c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2014. I am trying to call the stored procedure here and it results in 0 rows with a

> "Enumeration yielded no results"

message. It's not an error. How can I solve this problem?

My speculation is, of with the parameters, especially with DateTime class. I also used `SqlDateAdapter`, still, I had the same results.

Following is the code. Thanks in advance

```
public HttpResponseMessage GET()
{
        string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xyz"].ConnectionString;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        SqlDataReader reader;
        string testDate1 = "2017-01-16";
        DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(testDate1, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        string testDate2 = "2016-12-16";
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(testDate2, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[4];
        parameters[0] = new SqlParameter("@date1", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        parameters[0].Value = testDate1;

        parameters[1] = new SqlParameter("@date2", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        parameters[1].Value = testDate2;

        parameters[2] = new SqlParameter("@order", SqlDbType.Int);
        parameters[2].Value = 2;

        parameters[3] = new SqlParameter("@limit", SqlDbType.Int);
        parameters[3].Value = 100;

        try
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText="dbo.[abc]";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();

            foreach(SqlParameter sprocParams in parameters){
                cmd.Parameters.Add(sprocParams);
            }

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.HasRows){
                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(0));
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch(SqlException sqe){
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sqe.Message);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sqe.StackTrace);
        }
}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?  Incidentally, you can skip the for loop for adding the parameters.  Just use `cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);`

Comment: If you run the stored procedure from SSMS with the same parameters, does it return rows? Can you post the stored procedure?

Comment: i got it guys, the moment after i posted this. my bad. its a very silly mistake. i swapped the date 1 and date 2. sproc was expecting it in an order.
Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Your passing the reference to the string instead of the datetime.

```
parameters[0] = new SqlParameter("@date1", SqlDbType.DateTime)
parameters[0].Value = dt1;
```

Comment: i got it guys, the moment after i posted this. my bad. its a very silly mistake. i swapped the date 1 and date 2. sproc was expecting it in an order. Thank you though!